# request.POST.getlist returns a list of strings - how to get integers instead

Tags: python, django

I have some form fields, say:

```
<input name="item" value="2">
<input name="item" value="3">
<input name="item" value="4">
```

When I obtain these in my Django view by using getlist, I obtain the following:

```
items = request.POST.getlist("item")
# items = ['2', '3', '4']
```

Is there a way to get these as integers and not strings? Or should I convert these to integers manually (eg through list comprehension)?

Comment: `map(int, items)`

Comment: When you dont specify the type of input it is text which returns string. Try specifying type to number and see if it returns integer.

Comment: @Summer: that will not make a difference. A HTTP request is always text, so the headers/body of a request is text. The context of the form is "lost", so that means that it simply copies the values. One can later parse these values to an int, but the protocol in between is text.

Answer (score 1):

Try mapping and then parsing to int:

```py
items_str = request.POST.getlist("item")
# items_str = ['2', '3', '4']

# Maps each string to an int
items_map = map(int, items_str)

# Converts mapped output to a list of ints
items_int = list(items_map)

print(items_int)
# [2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, you will receive inputs as list of strings when accessing `request.POST.getlist("item")`. Also, `request.POST.get("item")` would return a string as well even if the input type is number such as `<input type="number">`

If you require/expect to receive integers, I would recommend to manually convert the received list to list integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
price = request.POST.getlist('priceList[]')
```

use this in django view

Answer (score 0):

```
items = "".join(request.POST.getlist("item"))
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?